# Can I use same Form twice for django SessionWizard?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-formwizard

I am trying to create a SessionWizardView for a trip creation process.  The trip might have one leg (one way) or two legs (round trip).  Each leg has similar schema so I would like to use the same Form for both step 0 and step1, with a condition saying only to use step1 when the flight is round trip.

The problem I am having is that my "submit" button keeps loading step 0 over and over again instead of moving on to step 1 as it should for a round trip flight. (I am prepopulating each of the forms based on previously requested trip info for each leg in the get_form_initial() override).  My form populates correctly for the first leg, it just populates the first leg data on every submit ad infinitum.

I *could* make two identical forms, but that seems like poor practice.  Slightly better, I could have the Return trip form just inherit from the Outbound trip form and not make any changes to it - this is what I'll try next barring a better solution.

But, I'm really wondering if there is there a way to use the same form twice?

In my urls.py:

```
wizard_forms = [TripCreationForm,TripCreationForm]

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^trip/wizard/(?P<pk>\d+)$',
    views.CreateTripSetView.as_view(wizard_forms,
         condition_dict=  {'1':show_return_trip_form}), name='admin_add_tripset')
```

)

in views.py:

```
 def show_return_trip_form(wizard):
     """
     Tells the CreateTripSetView wizard whether to show the return trip form
     Args:
        wizard:

    Returns: True if this is a round trip, false if one-way

    """
    cleaned_data = wizard.get_cleaned_data_for_step('0') or {}
    if cleaned_data.get('total_legs') == 2:
        return True
    return False

class CreateTripSetView(SessionWizardView):

    def get_form_initial(self, step):
        """
        Populates the initial form data based on the request, route etc.
        THIS IS ALWAYS FIRING FOR STEP=0 WHEN I HIT SUBMIT.
        Args:
            step:

        Returns:

        """

        initial = self.initial_dict.get(step, {})
        triprequest = TripRequest.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs['pk']).first()
        if triprequest is None:
            return initial

        initial.update({
            'request_id': flight_request.id,
            #other fields set on initial here
        })
        return initial
```

in forms.py:

```
class TripCreationForm

    #field defs ex.
    request_id = forms.IntegerField()
    #etc.

    def __init__(self, initial, *args, **kwargs):
         object_data = {}
         object_data['request_id'] = initial['request_id']
         #etc.

         super(AnywhereFlightCreationForm, self).__init__(initial=object_data, *args, **kwargs)
```

Edited:
So far I've been able to make this work using two subclasses of TripCreationForm but not using TripCreationForm for both.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The wizard needs to identify them as separate steps. Maybe this would work?

```
wizard_forms = [
        ("form1", TripCreationForm),
        ("form2", TripCreationForm),
]
```

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't seem to work, it jumps straight to form2 in that scenario.